# How to run Application on Samsung Smarttv using Tizen studios?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I am trying to run my angularjs application on Samsung Tv and it is showing these errors

`Could not create the view: org.tizen.common.connection.log.LogView`
and this one also

> Launching the Tizen application...
>
> ## If you want to see the detailed information,
>
> ## please set the logging level to DEBUG in Preferences and check the log file in 'C:\tizen-studio-data\ide\logs/ide-20200102_110337.log'.
>
> [Initializing the launch environment...]
>       RDS: Off
>       Target information: UA43N5370
>       Application information: Id(LgHdyO9URO.SHOPLC), Package Name(LgHdyO9URO), Project Name(LC) [Transferring the package...]
>       Transferred the package: wgt stream -> /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/tmp/LC.wgt [Installing the package...]
>   install LgHdyO9URO.SHOPLC package_path
>   /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/tmp/LC.wgt was_install_app return
>   WAS_TRUE app_id[LgHdyO9URO.SHOPLC] install start
>   app_id[LgHdyO9URO.SHOPLC] download failed[116] spend time for wascmd
>   is [10]ms cmd_ret:0
>       An exception occurred (Installing the package... > Fail) An exception occurred Unexpected stop progress... (18.353 sec)

earlier it was working fine but after a few weeks when I tried to launch my application it's showing me error and i have tried multiple solutions but none of them worked please help me out